# JSTL EL accessor translation priority when get and is both exist?

Tags: java, jsp, reflection, jstl, el

This is sorta' a two-part question.

I have a person object with a char attribute on it called "active". Person has a getActive() method that returns a char as expected. In my JSTL EL, I have the following:

```
<c:if test="${person.active == '1'}">Active</c:if>
```

This never passes. My understanding is that quoted literals in JSTL are strings (regardless of single or double quote) and that the char type is being retained from the getActive call, so these two values are not equal when getActive() returns the character '1'.

As an alternative, I added an isActive() method which returns a boolean. In this case, the following works:

```
<c:if test="${person.active == true}">Active</c:if>
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is my understanding correct regarding the char comparison? If so, is there any way to convert the types in JSTL so that they are comparable?
2. When both getActive() and isActive() exist, which one gets called by the EL translation? It seems isActive() gets priority but is there an officially documented ordering to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is my understanding correct regarding the char comparison? If so, is there any way to convert the types in JSTL so that they are comparable?*

From chapter 1.8.2 of [EL 2.2 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) (emphasis mine):

> ## 1.8.2       `A {==,!=,eq,ne} B`
>
> - If `A==B`, apply operator
> - If `A` is `null` or `B` is `null` return `false` for `==` or `eq`, `true` for `!=` or `ne`.
> - If `A` or `B` is `BigDecimal`, coerce both `A` and `B` to `BigDecimal` and then:
>
>   - If operator is `==` or `eq`, return `A.equals(B)`
>   - If operator is `!=` or `ne`, return `!A.equals(B)`
> - If `A` or `B` is `Float` or `Double` coerce both `A` and `B` to `Double`, apply operator
> - If `A` or `B` is `BigInteger`, coerce both `A` and `B` to `BigInteger` and then:
>
>   - If operator is `==` or `eq`, return `A.equals(B)`
>   - If operator is `!=` or `ne`, return `!A.equals(B)`
> - **If `A` or `B` is `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer`, or `Long` coerce both `A` and `B` to `Long`, apply operator**
> - If `A` or `B` is `Boolean` coerce both `A` and `B` to `Boolean`, apply operator
> - If `A` or `B` is an `enum`, coerce both `A` and `B` to `enum`, apply operator
> - If `A` or `B` is `String` coerce both `A` and `B` to `String`, compare lexically
> - Otherwise if an error occurs while calling `A.equals(B)`, error
> - Otherwise, apply operator to result of `A.equals(B)`

The `char`/`Character` is in EL thus coerced and evaluated as `Long`. That can never equal to a string literal of `'1'`.

---

> *When both getActive() and isActive() exist, which one gets called by the EL translation? It seems isActive() gets priority but is there an officially documented ordering to this?*

From chapter 8.3.2 of [Javabeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) (emphasis mine):

> ### 8.3.2 Boolean properties
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>
> `public boolean is<PropertyName>()`;
>
> This “is<*PropertyName*>” method may be provided instead of a “get<*PropertyName*>” method, or it may be provided in addition to a “get<*PropertyName*>” method.
>
> **In either case, if the “is<*PropertyName*>” method is present for a boolean property then we will use the “is<*PropertyName*>” method to read the property value.**
>
> An example boolean property might be:
>
> ```
>     public boolean isMarsupial();
>     public void setMarsupial(boolean m);
> ```

This, in combination with the point right after the emphasized point in the previously quoted chapter 1.8.2 of EL spec,

> - If `A` or `B` is `Boolean` coerce both `A` and `B` to `Boolean`, apply operator

will give the `isXxx()` method precedence.

Comment: My Google skills must have failed me. Excellent answer, thank you for the specification references!

Comment: Quick follow-up if you don't mind: based on the coercion to of char to Long, wouldn't person.active == 1 be true (removed the quotes from '1')?  It's still not validating when c:out prints that person.active is indeed 1.

Comment: Do a `System.out.println((long) '1');` and compare to exactly this value. Better (more self-documenting) would be to use an `int`, `boolean` or even an `enum` instead though. `char` is rarely useful in EL.

Comment: Agreed regarding char. Unfortunately this model is mapped to an Oracle database via hibernate and Oracle doesn't support boolean as a column type. You're correct, though -- comparing to 49 (even with quotes) works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: The string would be coerced to `Long` by `Long#valueOf()`. I'd omit those quotes to save an extra coercion step, although performance impact is really minor.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is test the character's value, something like

```
<c:if test="${person.active.value == 1}">Active</c:if>
```

As to which one gets priority isXXX() or getXXX() it's pretty much implementation specific.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "implementation specific" comment? If you mean based on the context it's being compared to, let's say it's a c:out tag instead of a c:if, simply printing the value of person.active?

Comment: I mean that even if you try it in (let's say) Tomcat and you see that isActive is preffered to getActive, that doesn't mean it won't be the other way around in Glassfish or WebLogic.

Comment: Gotcha'. This was sorta' my fear... I was hoping there was a standard priority so I can safely use this approach as it seems a little more clean.

Comment: This is **definitely** not implementation specific. It's clearly specified in EL and Javabeans spec. Different behaviour would be a bug in the implementation used.

Comment: @Balus Yes I agree, never the less, this happends. At any rate, if JEE specs violations would really be punished, Hibernate would be out of business ;)