# What is the precedence of ambiguous (boolean/int) accessors in JSP Expression Language?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I'm dealing with a legacy system that has a Java bean with this (trimmed/masked) snippet:

```
public class AmbiguousJspElBean {
    private int ambiguous;

    public int getAmbiguous() {
        return ambiguous;
    }

    public void setAmbiguous(int ambiguous) {
        this.ambiguous = ambiguous;
    }

    public boolean isAmbiguous() {
        return ambiguous == 1;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. If I try to reference `ambiguous` in JSP Expression Language via `${bean.ambiguous}`, what is the precedence the interpreter uses to find the matching accessor?

   a. I've tested it out, and in practice, it seems to favor the `isAmbiguous()` method, but will that *always* be the case/does it depend on the interpreter I'm using?
2. Should I instead call `${bean.isAmbiguous()}` to (potentially) alleviate any ambiguity for future on-lookers?

As I've said, it's a legacy system, so modifying the original class to turn `ambiguous` into a `boolean` instead of an `int` isn't an option.

Comment: I suppose this behaviour is implementation dependent. I'm trying to find a proof of my idea but nothing for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9467565/5942609) already, defaulting to the boolean `public boolean is<PropertyName>()` accessor.

Comment: Aha! Thank you sir! Apparently my searching skills have failed me